# About cgdsr R package

Tags: r, vector

I installed cgdsr R package and I wanted to use a below function ranging from 0 to the end, which means I want to see all genes.
But I don't know how to set c(1:?) that is a vector of gene names or a String specifying a single gene (required) for all genes.

getProfileData(mycgds,**c(1:100)**,mygeneticprofile,mycaselist)

Comment: That function does not provide an "all genes" option. It sends the lists of genes you request to the server to only get back values for those genes you request. The package can only expose features offered by the official API which is described here: http://www.cbioportal.org/web_api.jsp